# Update data in ComboBox while form is still open

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, combobox

I have form in which I can change the name of stations in my database (SQL Server: in table Stations).

To choose which station I want to edit I've used a combobox.

What I want to happen now is that when I update a station, my ComboBox with stations immediatly gets updated with the edited station.

Is there a way to do this or is this impossible?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that this is a Windows Forms application based on the subject. If this is the case, then you have most likely performed databinding, perhaps using a DataTable or a collection, to the ComboBox.

If this is the case, and the object that you have databound supports System.ComponentModel.IBindingList, then all you need to do is add or update the record in the underlying object.

When this happens, the object that has implemented IBindingList sends a message out to any controls that are "listening" and tells them what just happened. The control will then update their data/user interface to reflect these changes.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm quite new to VB. Do I have to put in some code or just change some settings from my combobox in my designer in Visual Studio?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code that you are currently using and/or describe exactly how the combobox currently gets populated with data? There are several ways that this can be done, so until we know the exact approach you are currently using, we can only offer general advice.

Comment: I didn't use code for it, I've bound my data manually into the combobox with Visual Studio